# How to start CouchDB from command line

Tags: windows, couchdb, nosql

I know we can use net start and stop to manage a couchDB service on windows. I want to know if there alternate ways to manage couchDB. I want to create start and stop couchDB scripts like the ones used in the linux installation so that I can customize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have it installed as a service you can use the `couchdb.bat` file to start. Located here: `install_dir\bin`.

Comment: To start this works. Any ideas on how to stop CouchDB?

Comment: to stop service in windows open cmd as administrator and run - net.exe stop "apache couchdb"

Comment: I get an error when I double click `couchdb.cmd`. I have the latest version installed. I created my own batch file like so `net.exe start "apache couchdb" `.

Answer (score 0):

[**Click here for snapshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svHBK.png)

Managed here start and stop by selecting.

Another way: How to start CouchDB from command line

access your directory where installed couch db like on window cmd:

C:\CouchDB\bin

C:\CouchDB\bin> couchdb stop
C:\CouchDB\bin> couchdb restart